# Both windows and linux unable to open laptop integrated webcam stream

Tags: linux, windows, video, webcam

#### Device

I use a **Lenovo Yoga Slim 7i Pro** with Pop_OS 22.04, Windows 11 and elementary OS 6.1 currently installed in it. The device supports windows hello and hence has an IR webcam built in too, I believe.

#### Problem

I have been unable to access my integrated webcam from both linux and windows on my laptop for over a month now. It worked just fine up until then and I regularly used windows hello too. Both the OSes are able to recognize and list the camera just fine, and the LED next to the camera turns on each time some software tries to access it, but no software seems to be able to be able to actually read the output.

##### Application Behaviour

VLC on linux reports an error for 2 of the 4 video streams available and just displays a black screen for the other 2 streams([log](https://pastebin.com/LAycZr0J)).
Cheese too shows a blank screen.

The default Camera application on windows displays a grayed out screen and sometimes complains that another application is using it. Windows device manager doesn't see anything wrong with the hardware and trying to mess around with the drivers on windows too hasn't done much.

Web browsers are also unable to open the camera output.

#### Context

I don't know what caused the camera to stop working like this, and it is possible that I noticed it only after a while, but I think it may have had something to do with my trying to set up using my android phone as a webcam using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/). I was following the instructions [here](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/v4l2.md) without really understanding much of what was happening, and it didn't work either.

#### Debug info

I'm just including some of the outputs I've seen asked for in general, please do ask for others that are required.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 4, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
```

```
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-1):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media0
    /dev/media1
```

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep video
[    3.051298] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    5.650006] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    5.772633] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

```
$ udevadm info -a /dev/input/by-id/usb-Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._Integrated_Camera_0001-event-if00

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input11/event5':
    KERNEL=="event5"
    SUBSYSTEM=="input"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_usage}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input11':
    KERNELS=="input11"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{capabilities/abs}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ev}=="3"
    ATTRS{capabilities/ff}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/key}=="100000 0 0 0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/led}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/msc}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/rel}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/snd}=="0"
    ATTRS{capabilities/sw}=="0"
    ATTRS{id/bustype}=="0003"
    ATTRS{id/product}=="b6cb"
    ATTRS{id/vendor}=="04f2"
    ATTRS{id/version}=="8018"
    ATTRS{inhibited}=="0"
    ATTRS{name}=="Integrated Camera: Integrated C"
    ATTRS{phys}=="usb-0000:00:14.0-1/button"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{properties}=="0"
    ATTRS{uniq}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uvcvideo"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Integrated Camera"
    ATTRS{physical_location/dock}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/horizontal_position}=="center"
    ATTRS{physical_location/lid}=="yes"
    ATTRS{physical_location/panel}=="front"
    ATTRS{physical_location/vertical_position}=="upper"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 5"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="8018"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}=="Integrated Camera"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="b6cb"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f2"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd."
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{physical_location/dock}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/horizontal_position}=="center"
    ATTRS{physical_location/lid}=="yes"
    ATTRS{physical_location/panel}=="front"
    ATTRS{physical_location/vertical_position}=="upper"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="335648"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="2"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="2000"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="6747712"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/persist}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="338292"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="6408242"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="Integrated Camera"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="fixed"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0001"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="70413"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.01"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0602"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 6.2.6-76060206-generic xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="12"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="1886500"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="6747844"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="1887413"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="4859526"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="571"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{dbc}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{device}=="0xa0ed"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="0"
    ATTRS{irq}=="148"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/148}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="1890693"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="suspended"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="4856925"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D3hot"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x30"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3864"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/async}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_kids}=="10"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_enabled}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_usage}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

[VLC log](https://pastebin.com/LAycZr0J)

Comment: Lenovo laptops have a camera-lock key in the top-row of the keyboard, which will hardware-deactivate the video  stream. Usually it's `FN+F8`. If that doesn't help, try to open the Lenovo Vantage software in Windows, or check in BIOS.

Comment: @1NN There doesn't seem to be a camera-lock key in the top row for this model, I tried them all - F8 was airplane mode. I had tried Vantage and even that complains after some time that the camera is being used by another application. I tried disabling some features like auto-lock auto-playback and windows hello too, which didn't help either. I wasn't able to find pretty much anything to do with the camera in the UEFI interface in the laptop.